# How to tell which document was just added in firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

in python, i am watching a firestore collection for changes and for each change i receive a snapshot containing the whole collection. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen.html#view_changes_between_snapshots) this is not a problem, however, my problem is that each document in that snapshot has a change type of 'ADDED', so how should i determine which document was just added?

```
#callback Function
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print('on_snapshot..')
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            #this is the new document.. 
            #which of the documents in the snapshot are of change.type.name = 'ADDED'?
        else:
            #some modified/deleted document..
```

Comment: The documents which triggered the event would be in your snapshot listener in the ADDED case.

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e in my case i am getting all the documents in the ADDED case.

Comment: Basically your snapshot listener provides you the data which you requested and in addition to that, it also instantly gives you any changes in it. So you ADDED case means that some data has been added to the database, which you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it was in the documentation after all!

```
for change in changes:
    if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
        print(f'New document: {change.document.id}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which seems to me is - you just attach **timestamp** to each document and query for the documents according to the time. By this way you can see whose timestamp (*of creation*) is the latest and which is the old.

Hope it works out!

Comment: If that's something other than my answer so kindly post that answer and mark it correct (for the future readers) and if my answer satisfied your question, kindly mark it correct.